# Escape \n with VERTICAL IDEOGRAPHIC COMMA in JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to get this Object valid but it failed !

```
config.SEMINAIRES = JSON.parse(`{
  "0": { 
  "title": "Séminaire0", 
  "image_url": "http://placehold.it/800x800", 
  "subtitle": "subtitle du Séminaire 0 \n Prix : 23€ \n Durée : 3 heures", 
  "buttons": [{ "type": "web_url", "url": "http://www.aeazeaze.fr", "title": "Réserver" }, { "type": "postback", "title": "Détails", "payload": "CIRCUIT_0" }] }
}`);
```

I tried `\n` and `\\n` but nothing is working. How can I have a valid JSON Object please.

Comment: Why are you using JSON here at all? Why not directly use an object literal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
"subtitle": "subtitle du Séminaire 0 \\n Prix : 23€ \\n Durée : 3 heures"
```

Comment: I tried this 10 minutes ago ... It didn't worked ! You said "You need to escape the backslash", I tried again and now It works ! Thank you for your answer.